# Calling sizeof(*this) in a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, this, specialization

If I have two classes, with **B** being a specialization of **A** and **A** having a non-virtual function called size:

```
class A
{
  unsigned Size() {return sizeof(*this);}
}

class B: public A;
```

When I call the Size function from **B**, will it return the size of **B** or the size of **A** ? I would assume **B**, since the **this** keyword would evaluate into something different for each one, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 7):

First off, `sizeof` is **not** a function. It is a compile-time operator.

Because it is compile-time, it cannot possibly know about the pointed-to type of `this`. For any `class T`, `this` should always be considered as `T* this`. Even if it *actually* points to a derived type.

So, as Matt McNabb [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097412/calling-sizeofthis-in-a-derived-class#comment35305308_23097434), your code is equivalent to `return sizeof(A)`.

For this reason, your non-virtual `Size()` function will always return the size of the class it is defined in.  Now if you make it virtual, and override it in all classes, it should give a correct size for any of those classes, as determined by the compiler.

Comment: So, this wouldn't even compile ? Or would it be undefined behavior ?

Comment: It would compile and it's not undefined behavior. Nothing undefined about it except maybe that it doesn't do what you personally expected it to do.

Comment: @user3218083 Neither. It will compile and always return the size of `class A`.

Comment: Too bad, that was exactly what I was trying to avoid. I am sending some  messages over UDP using a simple Messaging system (cast into the correct type based on message id), so I was hoping this would get me the stride for each message without having to re-implement the code with each new message type.

Comment: @user3218083 You should probably reconsider sending raw objects over the network anyway, for a number of portability reasons (byte order, structure packing/alignment, member ordering, etc.)

Comment: You're sending objects over the network by just directly sending their binary representation? That's just not going to work across different architectures and compilers.

Comment: Then what should I use ? I basically want the server to send everything that must be drawn this frame for an Asteroids game. So sending those messages efficiently, and preferably, in bulk, is what I am aiming for. Using UDP is a project constrain, though.

Comment: It is best to come up with a well-defined protocol that ensures specific values are at pre-defined byte offsets in the datagram, sends multi-byte values in network-order, and allows room for expansion (new commands, etc.)